Fourier transform of product of tanh
Can someone help with the following Fourier transform:
\begin{equation}
\tanh(a + bx)\tanh(a - bx)
\end{equation}
I tried in several ways (convolution theorem, expansion in exponential functions, one tanh and one in exponential functions..) but to no avail.
It would be ok to obtain its Fourier transform also as a generalised function, if possible. Any pointers in general would be appreciated.

WolframAlpha doesn't give an answer either.

if WolframAlpha gave an answer I wouldn't be writing this post :)

I also tried on Mathematica in various sauces but no response

$$
\tanh\left(a + bx\right)\tanh\left(a -  bx\right) = {\tanh\left(a + bx\right) + \tanh\left(a -  bx\right) \over \tanh\left(2a\right)} - 1
$$

Using the sum formula
$\tanh(u+v)=\frac{\tanh (u)+\tanh(v)}{1+\tanh(u)\tanh(v)}$,
$$\tanh(a+bx)\tanh(a-bx)=\frac{\tanh(a+bx)+\tanh(a-bx)}{\tanh(2a)}-1$$
And the Fourier transform of $\tanh$ is $\mathcal F\left(\tanh\right)(\omega)=-i\pi\text{csch}(\frac{\pi\omega}2)$.
Can you finish?
